# Is there a way to fix missing icon in ubuntu 20 gui?

Tags: lubuntu, icons

I have install ubuntu desktop gui on lubuntu, it have alot of problem, but once I updated with `sudo do-release-upgrade`, everything seems to be working properly except there is some missing icon.. so i wonder if there is away to reinstall ubuntu default icon.

it's not a major problem, but it's kinda annoying seeing all those red squares.

thanks.

[image]

edit: for clarification, this is what I did.

I install lubuntu 18.04 into VM
afterward, I update the packages with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, then I install ubuntu desktop gui with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
than I upgrade to latest release with `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade`

this is what I mean by red square... it's some missing icon.
[image]

Comment: Lubuntu is a *deb* based desktop release, thus uses the *year.month* format unlike *snap* only releases like Ubuntu Core 20. There is no Lubuntu 20; so please clarify your release.  Ubuntu has had *yy* based releases for specialist products since 2016, and no *flavor* has had any, including Lubuntu  (*flavors* are all desktop releases which are *deb* based; GNOME exists in *snap* format, LXQt/LXDE does not)

Comment: If you read the Lubuntu 20.04 release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) you'll find "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  An effort was made to make it possible, but GUI issues will remain, which is why re-install was recommended.  I don't know if that's the cause, but your upgrade is unsupported (*by Lubuntu*)